# How to update a field value after action dispatched with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I would like to populate a form after an ajax call with redux.

My case is pretty simple:

- I have a simple user form (with only one text field for now), it's a react view bound to the state with `connect()`.
- I call a rest API to fetch the user.
- When the api call is done, an action is dispatched with the user.
- A reducer update the store state with the user.
- I would like to populate/update the form with the retrieved values.

**Solution 1:**

If I set the value from the props like that:

```
const Field = ({ field, onFieldChange, value }) => (
  <input 
    value={value} 
    onChange={(event) => { onFieldChange(field, event.target.value) }} 
    type="text" 
  />
)
```

It works but I get this warning:

```
Field is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa).
```

I understand why I get this error as I should not use a component to display something and also be able to update it.

I also tried to use the defaultValue props but this is only used at the component creation (and we don't have the user yet). After the ajax call return, defaultValue cannot be called.

**Solution 2:**

Use redux-form with a custom plugin to update the form model each time the state get updated. I don't find this solution really clean but maybe I'm wrong.

I really thin that I'm going in the wrong direction and that it should exist a better way.

Does somebody already faced this kind of issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem when I was trying to pass `undefined` as the input value.

To fix this, ensure that you are passing at least empty string to the input, not undefined

```
const Field = ({ field, onFieldChange, value }) => (
  <input 
    value={value || ''} // <- add fallback value here
    onChange={(event) => { onFieldChange(field, event.target.value) }} 
    type="text" 
  />
)
```

Comment: Awesome, it fixed it. I was so desperate, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

1. Actually you might try to make your component statefull - store and manage value of input inside of it ([they say it's ok](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/src/components/Explore.js#L22)).
2. Or if you really need this value in the store use redux-form, I have realy good experience of using it (you'll have to write less boilerplate code).
   By the way, you will not have to use any custom plugin, you can use `initialValues`, see more [here](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/examples/initializeFromState/)

The solution above will work for sure, but it doesn't seem to be nice.

Comment: initialValues doesn't work on the redux-form because when I initialize the form, the user is not fetched yet. So the form is initialized empty and I cannot update it afterward.

Comment: @JulienSanchez, if you look at example I've shown you, you'll see that there form is also initialized asynchronously (on button click). Moreover form can be initialized as many times as you want by dispaching
"INITIALIZE action yourself (using the action creator provided by redux-form)"

Comment: Yup, saw that but by a button inside the form. So kind of easy as you can dispatch from inside the form. Also, I don't find it really clean to have to dispatch an internal event from outside the form :/

Comment: You doesn't have to dispatch anything.
You should define your initialValues only what they will be loaded:

Comment: You doesn't have to dispatch anything.
You should define your initialValues only what they will be loaded:
https://github.com/kitos/web-purple/blob/master/src/containers/account-settings.tab.jsx#L51